# Ionic app logs user back in after log out then relaunching the app

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

```
logout : function() {
            loggedIn=false;
            window.localStorage['logindata']="";
            window.localStorage['userdata']="";
            service.saveToNativeStorage();
            $location.url('/map');
        },
```

```
$scope.logout = function() {
        AuthService.logout();
        AuthService.checkLogin();
window.localStorage.clear();
    };
```

```
var service =  {
        saveToNativeStorage:function(){
            if(typeof(NativeStorage) !== 'undefined') {
                stored.forEach(function(name){
                    if(window.localStorage[name]){
                        NativeStorage.setItem(name, window.localStorage[name], function(data){
                            // console.log('save', data);
                        }, function(error){
                            // console.log(name+':', error);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        loadFromNativeStorage:function(){
            if(typeof(NativeStorage) !== 'undefined') {
                stored.forEach(function(name){
                    NativeStorage.getItem(name, function(data){
                        if(data){
                            window.localStorage[name] = data;
                            // console.log('load', window.localStorage[name]);
                        }
                    }, function(error){
                        // console.log(name+':', error);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
```

I am trying to use

`$window.localStorage.clear();`

But I cannot get It to delete the local storage on logout. Whenever I relaunch the app, It logs the user back in automatically.

edited to add service saveToNativeStorage

Comment: even though localStorage is "sort of" synchronous I would still check if you are calling a URL redirect while actual methods are still writing to persistence.

Comment: hmmm ok I will check thank

Comment: can something like this work? ```<button class="button button-full icon-left am-logout button-positive" ng-click="logout(); sessionStorage.clear();">```

Comment: can you share what is in the service.saveToNativeStorage?

Comment: yes I edited the post to include it

Comment: @SergeyRudenko does that help?

Comment: Can you try and insert into your logout function a timeout between clearing storage data and last line ($location.url('/map');). This way you can at least triage this problem to confirm its async issue. Then let me know the result and we can solve it

Comment: yeah I will try that, I also have this line ```AuthService.loadFromNativeStorage();```
that if i comment it out it fixes my issue but I need that line there so I need another solution

Comment: @SergeyRudenko so if i could essentially 'unload' what is being loaded from AuthService.loadFromNativeStorage(); when the user logs out wouldn't that fix it?

Comment: so my suspicion is that in your logout function you have a url redirect (/map) that triggers auto login check and since the data is not fully cleared at that moment you get user logged in. With inserting time-out you can confirm or invalidate my theory:) as time-out will allow persistence to clear out

Comment: im not quite sure exactly how to do that the right way @SergeyRudenko

Comment: try wrapping your location.url call inside logout function with setTimeout: setTimeout(()=>{$location.url('/map')}, 2000);

Comment: If this does not help - can you share some how more of your code?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I actually ended up figuring out my issue.

Comment: very cool can you share it in the answer?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes! done.

Answer (score 0):

```
logout : function() {
        loggedIn=false;
        window.localStorage['logindata']=null;
        window.localStorage['userdata']=null;
        service.saveToNativeStorage();
        $location.url('/map');
    },
```

Comment: so all you needed is to do null vs empty string?:))

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.